# How to run "docker-compose up" pointing to a different image ID

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Apoligies if this question is dumb or naive... we are still learning docker. We are running Airflow in docker. Here are the docker images on our GCP compute engine:

```
ubuntu@our-airflow:~/airflow-dir$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
our-airflow_webserver   latest              aaaaaaaaaaaa        17 minutes ago      968MB
<none>                  <none>              bbbbbbbbbbbb        22 minutes ago      2.13GB
apache/airflow          2.1.4               cccccccccccc        5 weeks ago         968MB
<none>                  <none>              dddddddddddd        2 months ago        2.01GB
python                  3.7-slim-buster     eeeeeeeeeeee        17 months ago       155MB
postgres                9.6                 ffffffffffff        17 months ago       200MB
ubuntu@our-airflow:~/airflow-dir$
```

`dddddddddddd` was the image that used to run when we ran `docker-compose up` from the command line. However, we were testing a new Dockerfile, and built the new image `aaaaaaaaaaaa` with the tag `our-airflow_webserver`. `dddddddddddd` used to have this tag, but it was changed to `<none>` when we built `aaaaaaaaaaaa`.

We'd like to run `docker-compose up dddddddddddd`, however this does not work. We get the error `ERROR: No such service: dddddddddddd`. How can we create a container using the image `dddddddddddd` with docker-compose up? Is this possible?

**Edit:** If I simply run `docker run dddddddddddd`, I do not get the desired output. I think this is because our docker-compose file is launching all of the requisite services we need for airflow (webserver, scheduler, metadata db).

**Edit2:** Here's the seemingly relevant webserver part of our docker-compose file:

```
webserver:
    # image: 
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.Self
      context: .
```

can we simply uncomment `image`, and set it to `image: dddddddddddd` and then comment out the `build` part?

Comment: If you want `docker-compose` to use a different image, then edit your `docker-compose.yml` to specify the new image.

Comment: @larsks thanks for comment. see my latest edit. trying to understand how we would edit our `docker-compose.yml` for this.

Comment: If you're using `build` and you want to rebuild the image from the Dockerfile, then run first `docker-compose down` followed by `docker-compose up --build`.

Answer (score 1):

> can we simply uncomment image, and set it to image: dddddddddddd

Yes, you can. If you want to start the service with another image you must change the docker-compose.yml file.

> and then comment out the build part?

You don't need to comment the build part. The build just takes action when the image specified is not found or the `--build` option is passed as argument.

If you want to ensure that the image is not gonna be build, just pass the argument `--no-build` to `docker-compose up` command. This will avoid to build the image even if it's missing.

Check the `docker-compose up` [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) for further information.